# How many redis instances should be run on a machine in a redis cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Hola Redis Universe!!

We are planning to have the following configuration of redis cluster.

1. A redis cluster comprising of 5 nodes.
2. Each node to have 8 cores, and 64 GB RAM, and 100 GB SSD drive.
3. One slave per master instance.
4. Only RDB persistence(no AOF) after 15 mins on all instances.

We have expecting to have a large no of reads/writes per sec, a figure in excess of 20k+.

On each node, we are planning to have n masters and n slaves(of other nodes), Considering the singlethreaded nature of redis, we want to utilize the multiple cores. 
How many redis instances(masters and slaves) should be run on one node? ie. what should we use as the value of n? (2 masters/2 slaves or 3 masters/3 slaves)

I checked running multiple instances on local and CPU usage seemed to shoot up a lot during the time the RDB save was in progress. Running multiple instances will increase the problem because the times of various instances being saved will clash. Is it going to be a problem in production?

Thanks